# launching instance from AWS AMI gives error 'Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".'

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, macos-high-sierra

I am trying to launch an instance from AWS AMI that i created for my project from a  encrypted snapshot and while trying to ssh into this newly created instance it gives the below error

```
Please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".
```

the connect button of the instance also gives me command with root and not ubuntu so did I make any mistake while configuring the AMI.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your ssh is something like this "ssh -i <someName.pem> ubuntu@x.x.x.x"(Presuming you have used pem type authentication), default user for instances running ubuntu is 'ubuntu'

Comment: my ssh is ssh -i root@x.x.x.x and it is not ubuntu@x.x.x.x but then I cannot ssh using this as I get the above error

Comment: If thats an ubuntu instance try SSH'ing with ssh -i ubuntu@x.x.x.x, as i have mentioned, the default user is 'ubuntu' in instances with ubuntu as os, not root.

Comment: it is not working that way.. I am launching the instance from an AMI so i don't know if I did anything wrong to change the default user from ubuntu to root or how can i prevent this from happening

Comment: Even if its an instance created from AMI it doesnt matter, you are ultimately ssh'ing into a linux instance, are you using a .pem file for authentication?

Comment: but AWS does not allow me to enter and gives the above error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174026/discussion-between-yasasvee-and-dhaval-chheda).